# Unable to upload data to Media Libary

Tags: forms, uploads

I uploaded wordpress to my server. Everything works fine so far. But when I try to upload data to my media libary nothing happens. Doesn't matter if I click the "Select Files" or "browser uploader" just nothing happens. I never had those kind of problems before.
The permission for the wp-content/uploads/ folder is on 777. 
I have absolutely no conclusion what could be the problem here? Any suggestions?

Regards,
Nils

Comment: Set `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in your `wp-config.php` and add the errors showing up to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I now figured out that it has something to do with my template. When I activated Twentyeleven the media upload works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function load_scripts() {
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"));
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
} 

add_action('init', 'load_scripts');
```

I have found the problem now (for all the following readers).
In my template functions.php I've included the latest version of jQuery. So jQuery has been included in the admin panel too. The fact that Wordpress loads jQuery in the admin panel twice must have caused the issue. 
I solved this by adding the conditional tag is_admin to the function add_action

```
if(!is_admin()) {
add_action('init', 'load_scripts');
}
```

Comment: Better yet, instead of using `init` use `wp_enqueue_scripts` which does the admin check for you and only loads on the frontend. [See more](http://wpdevel.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/use-wp_enqueue_scripts-not-wp_print_styles-to-enqueue-scripts-and-styles-for-the-frontend/)